# how can I add a items in mongdb same obiectId and update quuantity

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[this is a screenshot,MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: allfruitsCollection.allfruitsorder index: *id* dup key: { _id: "62772f5266f2a42a9abaa9d5" }[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6PX.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Mongo DB's database to subtract and add a quantity from an item using the put method from a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139529/how-can-i-use-mongo-dbs-database-to-subtract-and-add-a-quantity-from-an-item-us)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 objects with the same ObjetcId in MongoDB, this is a unique field that's autogenerated by MongoDB for every object in your database.

You could add a field like "ItemId" and then you could have the same id on different objects in the "ItemId" field